# How to mock AWS SDK v3 for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-sdk-nodejs

I develop some AWS Lambdas using Node.js, which utilizes DynamoDB via AWS SDK v3.

I have no idea how to mock `DynamoDBClient` using jest properly for the unit testing.

```js
const LambdaTester = require('lambda-tester')

const {DynamoDBClient} = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb")
const handler = require('./my-handler').handler

describe('handler', function () {
  it('Handler should work properly', async function () {
    const response = {
      Item: {
        a: {S: 'a'},
        b: {S: 'b'}
      }
    }

    DynamoDBClient.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        send: () => response
      }
    })

    await LambdaTester(handler)
      .event({
         // ...
      })
      .expectResult((res) => {
         // ...
      })
    })
})
```

When I run the test, it seems like trying to execute the real code and throws me an exception.

```
ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found
   at deserializeAws_json1_0GetItemCommandError (./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/protocols/Aws_json1_0.ts:3128:39)
```

Comment: Looks like the above error isn't related with given code. Anyway you might have to mock `jest.mock("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb")` at the same level with `require` thing. If it doesn't work, can you share your handler code?

Answer (score 0):

This should help: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/mocking-modular-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v3-in-unit-tests/
You need to use `aws-sdk-client-mock` for mocking Dynamo DB.

Answer (score -2):

In case you want to test dynamoDB, this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-local) worked perfectly for me. What it does is to deploy dynamoDB locally during a suit case is executed. I used for dynamoDB v2 & v3.

**The only requirement is java installed in our machine (JRE) because use a [JAR file to deploy dynamo locally instead docker image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html) **.

Hope helps!